# How to add exceptions to executor service

Tags: java

I am trying to add exception handler to the Runnable interface.
Here is my code:

```
 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(){
   Runnable r1 =() ->{
             //some code
};
executor.execute(r1);


}
```

How to add exception handler to the runnable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a (checked) exception handler to the `Runnable` interface is just about equivalent to a `Callable<T>` interface.  I recommend looking into that to solve your problem, otherwise you can simply use a `try-catch` block.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public ResponseEntity<String> handleNotifications(){
    executor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            // Code here...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exception here...
        }
    });

    return ...
}
```